# Selecionando duas colunas no sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
id  name      gender    species  height_cm
1   Dave      male      human    180
2   Mary      female    human    160
3   Fry       male      cat      30
4   Leela     female    cat      25
5   Odie      male      dog      40
6   Jumpy     male      dog      35
7   Sneakers  male      dog      55
```

Preciso apresentar apenas as espécies com maior (height_cm) e em seguida o tipo de species, no caso o resultado tem que ser:

```
MAX(height_cm)  species
30               cat
55               dog
180              human
```

Por enquanto apenas consegui a primeira coluna da tabela com o seguinte código :

```
SELECT MAX(height_cm) FROM friends_of_pickles GROUP BY species
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou somente adicionar o campo `species`

```
SELECT MAX(height_cm), species FROM friends_of_pickles GROUP BY species
```

Comment: Salvou muito! obrigadão

Comment: Show, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como `aceita` para que assim possa ajudar os outros com a mesma dúvida.